# How in IntelliJ IDEA to convert simple folder to web folder?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to create a Web folder in the IntelliJ IDEA project?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to menu

> File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Select your web facet -> Plus
>   button

And here you can choose your folder and setup relative url where in your web app should be content of the folder.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure a web resource directory in the [module Web facet settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/web-resource-directory-path-dialog.html).